# JQuery getJSON() not working when checking email

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a registration page which checks another webmethod to see if the particular value exists in the DB.

For the email validation, I have

```
//Checks the email against the database.
$(emailTextbox).blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        email = encodeURI(escape($(this).val()));
        alert(email);
        $.getJSON('/CheckAvailable.aspx?' + email + ".email", function (results) {
            if (results.email == "true") {
                availabilityEmail.html('<img src="/App_Themes/DefaultTheme/misc/tick.png"/>');
                email = true;
                CheckValid();
            } else {
                availabilityEmail.html('<img src="/App_Themes/DefaultTheme/misc/cross.png"/>');
                email = false;
                CheckValid();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Which uses

```
private string GetEmail(string email)
{
    const string strSql =
        "SELECT memberEmail FROM someView WHERE memberEmail = @email";

    var sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)).Value = email;

    string rdr = (string)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();

    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rdr) ? "\"" + "email" + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + "false" + "\"" : "\"" + "email" + "\"" + " : " + "\"" + "true" + "\"" + "\n";
}
```

But it seems as though the `JQuery` method never posts when I use a `.`. I've even tried to escape it with `\\.`, but it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**
Using encodeURI or not makes no difference. Trying to convert the string to a value also, comes to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your application and check the JSON result that is being returned by pasting it in a JSON validator such as [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). By the looks of things, your JSON is missing commas.

Check out more about JSON [on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: I'm using a copy+paste version from the other validations (Username, nickname etc). I've already parsed the JSON, which works correctly. Its from JQuery -> Server, not Server -> JQuery

Comment: I'm no pro with jQuery but may I ask why you need the .email? could you not just use `$.getJSON("/CheckAvailable.aspx/GetEmail?" + email`

Comment: I could, although its just another way of pumping the ball. Wouldnt make a difference.

Comment: :( Good luck, sorry I can't be of any help then

Comment: :) Totally cool! I think its something obvious waiting to smack me in the face :/ Checked out your site though :) Good to see another South African with some good opinions :P